# cefsharp winform crashes frequently

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

cefsharp winform crashes frequently,I have declared in the program to catch unhandled exceptions, but the program still crashes, how to solve it?

system exception log:

```
Framework version: v4.0.30319
Explanation: The process terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception information: System.AccessViolationException
    In System.String.wcslen(Char*)
    In System.String.CtorCharPtr(Char*)
    In <Module>.CefSharp.Internals.CefStringVisitorAdapter.Visit(CefSharp.Internals.CefStringVisitorAdapter*, CefStringBase<CefStringTraitsUTF16>*)
```

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: The version is 92.0.251

Comment: Version 93 has fix that should resolve the crash.

Comment: Ok, let me try it, thanks for your reply.

Comment: If the problem reproduces with version 94 then you can join in the discussion at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/3838 I'll need an example that reproduces the problem.